# Offline voice typing alternative for Android?

Tags: android, offline, speech-recognition

I would like an alternative to the voice search application provided by Google's Voice Typing.

This is because Voice Typing puts out an annoying 'ding' sound when it starts recording/interpreting, which you can't turn off (turning media volume down to zero is not an option for me).

[I have asked a question about disabling this on Android SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128588/how-do-i-disable-the-google-voice-typing-voice-search-ding-sound), but wanted to see if there are any close alternatives. It needs to:

1. work offline
2. not mute the speaker when recording
3. have English (preferably some other common languages too, as I'm
   using it for Duolingo)

Comment: I'm not sure if it works offline, but a college once told me about fascinating experiences with Dragon (on Android, this would be [Dragon Mobile Assistant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.balerion), by the makers of Swype). Some alternatives are listed on my page for [Personal Assistants](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_personalassistants).

Comment: Thanks, yeah tried that and it doesn't work offline, also mutes the speaker

Comment: Ah, OK – sad to read. If you've already tried some more, maybe add that to your question so you don't get it recommended again :) Maybe one of the other candidates from the linked list is a better fit?

Comment: A big list! I'll try a few of these at some point.

Comment: "A big list" – and still incomplete :) Good luck! And remember my site when looking for Android apps – I try to keep the lists up-to-date and informative. If you miss something there, drop me a note :)

Comment: What should this tool actually *do* (for those that don’t know Google Voice Typing)? You said "search application" … what should it search exactly? Or do you need this as replacement for typing, no matter in which context?

Comment: It's for typing anywhere, yes.